# How to initialise static variables of class A in class B?

Tags: c++, static

I tried using a static func in class A.

```
class A {
    private:
        static int a, b;
        static void init(void) {
            a = 1, b=0;
        }
};

class B {
   private:
       A::init();
}
```

It is giving non-friend class cannot have a qualified name.

Comment: You can't have generic statements outside of functions. Define (and initialize) the static variables separately instead.

Comment: Thanks seems to work after addressing your comment!

Comment: Please create an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
class A {
    private:
       static int a;
    public:
       static void initialize();
       void addStatic();
       void getA();
};

class B {
    public:
        void initializeClassA();
};

int A::a = 10;

void A::addStatic() {
    ++a;
}

void A::getA() {
    return a;
}

void A::initialize() {
    a = 0;
}

void B::initializeClassA() {
    A::initialize();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    std::cout << "Before Adding - " << a.getA() << std::endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        a.addStatiic();
    }
    
    std::cout << "After Adding - " << a.getA() << std::endl;
    b.initializeClassA();
    std::cout << "After Reinitializing - " << a.getA() >> std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```